# Distance between two objects

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

So I've been trying to figure out how to find the distance between two objects on a canvas and I've exhausted most relevant links on Google with little success.

I'm trying to make it so that it calculates the distance between the drawn ovals and the line on the canvas.

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Escape")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=800, bg='white')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_line(100, 100, 200, 200, fill='black')
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.tracer)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def tracer(self, e):
        self.canvas.create_oval(e.x-5, e.y-5, e.x+5, e.y+5, fill='blue', outline='blue')
        rx = "%d" % (e.x)
        ry = "%d" % (e.y)
        print rx, ry
MyApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two circles:

```
dist = math.sqrt((circle1.x-circle2.x)**2 + (circle1.y-circle2.y)**2) - circle1.r - circle2.r
```

Kind of obvious, their Euclid distance is calculated using the Pythagorean theorem.

Point/segment:

```
 a = segment[1].y - segment[0].y
 b = segment[0].x - segment[1].x
 c = - segment[0].x * a - segment[0].y * b 
 dx = segment[1].x - segment[0].x
 dy = segment[1].y - segment[0].y
 nc0 = - segment[0].x * dx - segment[0].y * dy
 nc1 = - segment[1].x * dx - segment[1].y * dy
 if ((dx * x + dy * y + nc0) < 0) dist = math.sqrt((x-segment[0].x)**2 + (y-segment[0].y)**2)
 elif((dx * x + dy * y + nc1) < 0) dist = math.sqrt((x-segment[1].x)**2 + (y-segment[1].y)**2)
 else dist = (a*x + b*y + c) / math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
```

Circle/segment - same as point/segment, just substract circle's radius

Polygon/polygon - Loop through each vertex of polygon 1 and segment of polygon 2, then loop through each vertex of polygon 2 and segment of polygon 1, then find the smallest.

Don't use magic numbers inside your code. That radius of 5 isn't good.

Comment: My biggest issue is that I am new to coding and I have a hard time understanding complicated code such as this. Most resources on the internet are too complicated for my knowledge of coding to comprehend. I'm looking for a simple thorough explanation of how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dist = math.sqrt((oval.x-point.x)**2 + (oval.y-point.y)**2)
```

not really sure if this answers your question but this is the distance formula

there are several problems with the original question.

1. at what point are you trying to find the distance?
2. you are not saving the oval positions so it will be very hard to look up later
3. why are you trying to get the distance?/what are you planning on doing with it?
4. are you trying to find distance to edge or distance to center?

in general I would guess you want to get it in the `def trace` function

step 1. Point of interest is (`e.x,e.y`)

step 2. Find the closest point on the line  (line = (100,100) to (200,200) ) (this is probably a question in its own right. http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-vector-mathematics-and-bit-of_08.html )

step 3. Apply distance method to point of interest and closest point on line

```
def dist(pt1,pt2):
    return ((pt1.x-pt2.x)**2 + (pt1.y-pt2.y)**2)**.5
```

on another side note ... your ovals look an awful lot like circles ...

Comment: For the OP's reference, this is what wikipedia calls the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) you may have seen it in math class :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand the code that well (I am new to coding and pretty bad at it). Would you mind explaining where all that comes from?

Comment: It comes from mathematics. `**` is exponentiation. `math.sqrt` is taking a **sq** uare **r** oo **t**.

Comment: See the "Other forms" section on the wikipedia page. `**2` means "squared", `math.sqrt` is the square root operation. (Oops, too slow)

Comment: So I edited the original code to add saving the positions of the ovals. To answer your question I am trying to find the distance because I am making a basic game where you have to navigate the mouse though a path without touching the edges, but I'm still trying to get the concept of not touching the line down.